# Gson library, cast JsonObject to MyObject

Tags: java, android, json, casting, gson

Im currently using this code to create Objects out of JsonStrings from my Server:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject myJsonObject = (JsonObject) parser.parse(myInputStreamReader);
MyObject myObject = new Gson().fromJson(myJsonObject.toString(), MyObject.class);
```

This works pretty good in most cases, but sometimes, the objects are pretty big and therefor `myJsonObject.toString()` causes a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Is there a possibility to cast `JsonObjects` directly to the specified object without casting them to a string first?

I already bypassed the `OutOfMemmoryError` for JsonObject-creation by using the `StreamReader` instead of a `String` and now i have exactly the same problem again, just a few lines under it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you parsing the JSON stream to a JSON object, then transforming back the JSON object to a string, then transforming back this string to a MyObject? Just do the last part, and everything will be much faster, and use less memory.

```
MyObject myObject = new Gson().fromJson(myInputStreamReader, MyObject.class);
```

Comment: I wrote a method to fetch the data from my server and wanted to keep all components of that HttpConnection (including the StreamReader) in that method. As there are different Objects i used that method to return a JsonObject and then casted the JsonObject to the "MyObject" in another Method.

Tanks for your suggestions. If there isnt a way to cast the Objects, ill change my method to return the StreamReader and create MyObject directly

Comment: Then at least use `fromJson(myJsonObject, MyObject.class)` without transforming bacj to String and force Gson to re-parse.

Comment: Thanks again. Didnt know that this is possible. I thought fromJson() can only handle Streams or Strings!

Comment: I had no idea either, so I just looked at the javadoc: http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html